# OpenGL - Maximizing / minimizing the output window resizes object inside. How can I avoid this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, graphics

How can I make sure that the output window is either fixed, or the circle output in the window does not change shape every time I maximize/minimize the window in OpenGL. I am using c++ on Visual Studio 2019 (meaning glew and glut dependencies have been set.) I am trying to create a circle using Midpoint drawing algorithm (radius 5cm, starting point coordinates (0,3)) and making sure it rotates 90 degrees afterward.

Note the screenshot shows the circle changed to oval shape after minimizing the window.[Screenshot link...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxApw.png)

Code:

```
    #include <Windows.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int xForRotation = 000;
int yForRotation = 120;
int rFlag;
double theta = 0.0;

void myinit(void)
{
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glutInitWindowSize(1000,1000);
    gluOrtho2D(-1*640.0, 640.0, -1*640.0, 640.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
void circleMidPoint()
{
    int xCenter = 000;
    int yCenter = 240; //3cm
    int radius = 400; //5cm

    int x = 0;
    int y = radius;
    int p = 1 - radius;//5/4 is rounded to 1 for integer radius

    while (x < y) {// iterates to draw the first sector
        x++;
        if (p < 0)// the mid point is inside the circle
            p += 2 * x + 1;
        else {// the mid point is outside or at the circle
            y--;
            p += 2 * (x - y) + 1;
        }
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2i(xCenter + x, yCenter + y);
        glVertex2i(xCenter - x, yCenter + y);
        glVertex2i(xCenter + x, yCenter - y);
        glVertex2i(xCenter - x, yCenter - y);
        glVertex2i(xCenter + y, yCenter + x);
        glVertex2i(xCenter - y, yCenter + x);
        glVertex2i(xCenter + y, yCenter - x);
        glVertex2i(xCenter - y, yCenter - x);
        glEnd();
    }
    // OPTIONAL:-> center of the circle
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(xCenter, yCenter);
    glEnd();
}
void display()
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);     // clear the screen  
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);          // red foreground
    glPointSize(5.0);// size of points to be drawin (in pixel)

    //establish a coordinate system for the image

    circleMidPoint();
    glFlush(); // send all output to the display

    glLoadIdentity();

        if (rFlag == 1) //Rotate the circle around fixed point
            {
                yForRotation;
                xForRotation;
                theta = 0.25;
            }
        glTranslatef(xForRotation, yForRotation, 0.0);
        glRotatef(theta, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glTranslatef(-xForRotation, -yForRotation, 0.0);
        glutPostRedisplay();
        glutSwapBuffers();


}

void rotateMenu(int option){
    if (option == 1)
        rFlag = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480); // set the size of the window
    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10); // the position of the top-left of window
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutCreateWindow("Midpoint Circle Drawing Algorithm. *Right CLick to Rotate");
    myinit();
    glutDisplayFunc(display); // set the gl display callback function
    glutCreateMenu(rotateMenu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Rotate Circle", 1);
    glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);
    glutMainLoop(); // enter the GL event loop
}
```

Comment: Do you update the viewport ([`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml)) and projection after resize?

Comment: No, I haven't. How is it used?

Answer (score 0):

The reflect the new size of the window, you have to add a [`glutReshapeFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node48.html) callback. In the callback you have to adapt the viewport rectangle to the new size by [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glViewport.xml). 
Further more you have to adapt the orthographic projection to the new size of the window.

The window size has to be set before the window is created. Later calls to [`glutInitWindowSize`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node11.html) have no effect.

Since the orthographic projection is set in  `reshape`, It is not necessary to set it in `myinit`.

```cpp
void myinit(void)
{
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
}

void reshape(int width, int height) {
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-width, width, -height, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // [...]

    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    glutCreateWindow("Midpoint Circle Drawing Algorithm. *Right CLick to Rotate");

    // [...]

    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

    // [...]
}
```